Backup Not Completed - Time Machine
I hope some of you can help me solve this bug. I'm trying to back up my macOS with a new Toshiba hard disk, but each time I run it, I receive the following warning: "Time Machine couldn’t complete the backup to 'EXTERNAL_US' - An error occurred while starting the backup. Antivirus software may be preventing Time Machine from writing to the backup." As shown in the screenshot below, I don't have any antivirus software installed on my Mac, by the way.


What year and model is your Mac and which macOS is installed on it?

If the disk does not have other needful data on it I would be tempted to try deleting all the partitions and making it one big HFS+ partition. It's quick and easy to do so and should fix any problems with the partition map.

In Disk Utility, can you determine the status of that disk and edit those details into your post? Without that, we can say - contact Apple Support, use a new backup disk, erase this disk and start again or let's review every piece of third party software to tell if you installed something that Apple classifies as Anti Malware.
